# C# -Take a string between a text

Tags: c#, string, split, between

I've got various string in a list:

> Ord.cl. N. 2724 del 08/11/2019

and it can be also

> > Ord.cl. N. 2725/web del 08/11/2019

I have to take all the content that comes after 'N.' and before 'del'. As result I want

- 2724
- 2725/web

Can someone do code for that in C#? I know there is substring, but maybe there are better ways?

Comment: Sounds like Regex ist a perfect tool for this.

Comment: What have you tried? We can help you with your doubts, but we're not here to code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can build some extention method like this

```
    public string SubstringFromTo(this string input, int from, int to)
    {
        return input.Substring(from, (to - from));
    }
    public string SubstringFromTo(this string input, string from, string to)
    {
        var index1 = input.IndexOf(from) != -1 ? input.IndexOf(from) : 0;
        var index2 = input.IndexOf(to) != -1 ? input.IndexOf(to) : (input.Length - 1);
        return input.SubstringFromTo(index1, index2);
    }

    var asd = " ciao ** come stai ? asdasd".SubstringFromTo("**","?");
```

result = "come stai"
//.Trim() if you want

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions, you might do:

```
var m = Regex.Match("Ord.cl. N. 2724 del 08/11/2019", @"(?<=N\.).*?(?=del)");
if (m.Success)
{
    var result = m.Value;
}
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

- `(?<=N\.)` looks for a preceding "N.".
- `.*?` matches any sequence of characters, but as few as possible
- `(?=del)` lools for a trailng "del".

Comment: using "(?:N\.\s*)(.*?)(?:\s*del)" and using the first capturing group one could avoid the whitespace in the result

Answer (score 0):

If it's always that predictable (space before and after `N.` and space before and after `del`), then it's fairly simple. Use [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) and use [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) to find the occurrences of `N.` and `del`:

```
var theString = "Ord.cl. N. 2725/web del 08/11/2019";

var start = theString.IndexOf("N. ") + 3;
var length = theString.IndexOf(" del", start) - start;

var partIWant = theString.Substring(start, length).Trim();

Console.WriteLine(partIWant);
```

That also assumes that there will only ever be one occurrence of `N.` and `del` in your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i< list.Count-1; i++)
        {
           NDocList.Add(list[i].DocumentiOrigine.Split(new string[] { " N. " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]
            .Split()[0]
                .Trim());
        }
```

solved with this somehow.